# Batch Text Replacement

Tags: batch, processing

I need a tool that can open a text file and replace characters in a list with other characters in a list.

For example:

Lets say I have a list of "aA", "aB", and want to replace "aA" with "AA".

What is a software program that could do this easily?

Comment: Virtually any scripting language can handle this easily: AutoIt, Python, Perl, etc.

Comment: I tried this with python but the logic has not been working properly so now I need a tool.

Comment: Try notepad++, you can do batch string replacement over many files: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/, or you can post your Python code and have a mod move this over to StackOverflow.com and they will help you out there.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what the `sed` program was made for.

Comment: well, if he means change lowercase chars to uppercase, then  perhaps not so easy with sed.   if he means just changing some specifics, like aA to AA, then yes.

Comment: Or `ex`.  Or indeed `tr` if using `sed` to change case is seen as hard (which, with GNU `sed` at least, it really isn't).

Answer (score 1):

As a Perl one-liner, to replicate sed functionality...

```
perl -pe " s/aA/AA/g; s/aB/AB/g; " < input.txt > output.txt
```

This will turn this input.txt...

```
aA, aA, aA, aA, aA
aB, aB, aB, aB, aB
```

into this output.txt...

```
AA, AA, AA, AA, AA
AB, AB, AB, AB, AB
```

It does this through regular expression substitution...

```
s(ubstitute)/this-original-string/with-this-new-string/g(lobally)
```